arduino as component espressif vscode
I'm developing a project of telemetry using esp-32. I put the codes with the libraries and when i pressed the "ESP-IDF: Build `Project" looks like a mistake. Can you help me ?
I wait the retorn.
Follow the BUG:
FAILED: esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp.obj
C:\Users\victor.martins.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -DESP_PLATFORM -DIDF_VER="v5.1.3" -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE="mbedtls/esp_config.h" -DSOC_MMU_PAGE_SIZE=CONFIG_MMU_PAGE_SIZE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/build/config -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/variants/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/cores/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/ArduinoOTA/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/AsyncUDP/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/BLE/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/BluetoothSerial/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/DNSServer/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/EEPROM/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/ESP_I2S/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/ESP_NOW/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/ESP_SR/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/ESPmDNS/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Ethernet/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/FFat/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/FS/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/HTTPClient/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/HTTPUpdate/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Insights/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/LittleFS/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/NetBIOS/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Network/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/PPP/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Preferences/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/RainMaker/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/SD_MMC/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/SD/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/SimpleBLE/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/SPIFFS/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/SPI/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Ticker/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Update/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/USB/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/WebServer/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/NetworkClientSecure/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/WiFi/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/WiFiProv/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/Wire/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal_I2C/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/MFRC522/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/libraries/INA226/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/cores/esp32/libb64 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/freertos/esp_additions/include/freertos -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/freertos/esp_additions/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/freertos/esp_additions/arch/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/heap/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/log/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/soc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/hal/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/include/private -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/freertos/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32xx/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32xx/include/arch -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_partition/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/esp_crt_bundle/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/3rdparty/everest/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/3rdparty/p256-m -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/3rdparty/p256-m/p256-m -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/wifi_provisioning/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/protocomm/include/common -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/protocomm/include/security -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/protocomm/include/transports -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/protocomm/include/crypto/srp6a -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/wifi_apps/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant/port/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant/esp_supplicant/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_adc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_adc/interface -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_adc/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_adc/deprecated/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/deprecated -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/analog_comparator/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/dac/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/gpio/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/gptimer/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/i2c/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/i2s/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/ledc/include
-IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/mcpwm/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/parlio/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/pcnt/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/rmt/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/sdio_slave/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/sdmmc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/sigma_delta/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/spi/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/temperature_sensor/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/touch_sensor/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/twai/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/uart/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/usb_serial_jtag/include
-IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/driver/touch_sensor/esp32/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/http_parser -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/chmorgan__esp-libhelix-mp3/libhelix-mp3/pub -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/fatfs/diskio -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/fatfs/vfs -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/fatfs/src -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/sdmmc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/app_update/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support/bootloader_flash/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_app_format/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/spiffs/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_hid/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_https_ota/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/esp_http_client/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/dotprod/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/support/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/support/mem/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/hann/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/blackman/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/blackman_harris/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/blackman_nuttall/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/nuttall/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/windows/flat_top/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/iir/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/fir/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/add/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/sub/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/mul/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/addc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/mulc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/math/sqrt/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/mul/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/add/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/addc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/mulc/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/sub/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/fft/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/dct/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/conv/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/common/include
-IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/matrix/mul/test/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/kalman/ekf/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-dsp/modules/kalman/ekf_imu13states/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-zboss-lib/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp-zigbee-lib/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp_insights/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp_diagnostics/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp_modem/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__esp_rainmaker/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__rmaker_common/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__mdns/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/console -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/espressif__qrcode/include -IC:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/managed_components/joltwallet__littlefs/include -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address -fdiagnostics-color=always -ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-enum-conversion -gdwarf-4 -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name=. -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/victor.martins/esp/v5.1.3/esp-idf=/IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -DconfigENABLE_FREERTOS_DEBUG_OCDAWARE=1 -std=gnu++2b -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_ESP32_DEV -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP32_DEV" -DARDUINO_VARIANT="esp32" -DESP32 -MD -MT esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf\arduino\CMakeFiles__idf_arduino.dir\cores\esp32\chip-debug-report.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp
C:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp: In function 'void printPartitionsInfo()':
C:/Users/victor.martins/esp/project-name/components/arduino/cores/esp32/chip-debug-report.cpp:196:18: error: 'ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_LITTLEFS' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_SPIFFS'?
196 | case ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_LITTLEFS: chip_report_printf("LITTLEFS"); break;
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_SPIFFS
[1133/1286] Building C object esp-idf/arduino/CMakeFiles/__idf_arduino.dir/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-misc.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Looks like there's an error related to the ESP partition subtype ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_DATA_LITTLEFS not being declared. All required dependencies and libraries for LittleFS should be included in your project and properly configured. Check your project configuration regarding the use of LittleFS.You have to configure LittleFS in your project's partition table properly. Hope this problem will be figured out soon.
Here is a github thread about a similar error, not the same through:
https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESPAsync_WiFiManager/discussions/96
Since, you are making a telemetry project using ESP32,you can make a Espressif ESP32 Board with LAN8720 and POE power suply like this: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Espressif_ESP32_Board_with_LAN8720_and_POE_power_suply_db192eb5.html
